# need help on gmail sso

Tags: java, struts2, gmail, single-sign-on

I am developing a web application using strut2 framework and using gmail credentials for login to that application. I am able to use google account services for login purpose successfully. Now I am trying to implement SSO between gmail & my application. The use case is "If user is already logged into gmail, I want that user to log automatically into my application".
How should I go about it?

Comment: I was doing a similar thing and found that google redirects to permission page even though the permission has already been given. This is annoying. Facebook on other hand does return a token directly if the permission is already given.

Comment: @subirkumarsao ... How did you go about implementing with google? If you could share some links?

Comment: This link is good one https://developers.google.com/accounts/